# register for an event in Windows

Tags: .net, c++, operating-system, wmi-service

Hi
I want to do something when a memory stick attached to PC. Now I use a timer and check it in every tick whether any memory stick is plugged(use DriveInfo or with querying WMI)
Is there any event driven model available to do? for example i use an event in my program that raise whenever a memory stick is plugged in to computer?

Comment: @dr_csharp: What is ***sth***?

Comment: @KMan, `s` is a variable and `s`-th is an ordinal number.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715739/looking-for-c-code-for-detecting-removable-drive-usb-flash) might help.

Comment: @Avakar: Shouldn't it be *n* th?

Comment: Then please write "something"

Comment: @KMan: "sth" is Nerd for "I'm a dork with no social interaction skills"

Comment: @John: Or "my time is so extremely valuable that saving a dozen keypresses for *me* is worth no amount of wasted time for *you* trying to decipher my question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to handle the [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28VS.85%29.aspx) message in your wndproc.  When you handle that, you can also call `RegisterDeviceNotification` to get notification that the stick is being cleanly ejected.

When you recieve a `WM_DEVICECHANGE`, you want to check the wParam - `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` (0x800) is what you're looking for.

In C++, you should have no trouble with the wndproc.  In c#, you'll want to override your main form's [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) method and check `m.Msg == 0x219` and `m.WParam == 0x800`. Note that not ALL of these will be a memory stick - but you can use this to notify you to check for drive insertion rather than a timer.

Comment: I don't know why when i do this, as I plug memory stick to PC, it raises more than 3 times ! following code is in C# :
        
            if (m.Msg == 0x219 && m.WParam == 0x800)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("this is a test");
            }

Comment: It will raise multiple times as the device type is recognized and refined.

Comment: This work properly :  when m.Msg==0x219 and m.WParam==32768 it means "Plugged In" and when m.WParam=32772 it means "Plugged out"