# How to use a FileSystemWatcher for monitoring new drives

Tags: c#, .net, windows, filesystemwatcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for C# code for detecting removable drive (usb flash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715739/looking-for-c-code-for-detecting-removable-drive-usb-flash)

How could the `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` class be used to detect drives (e.g. F:) being connected/disconnected under windows? If this is not possible, what other event driven ways are possible (other than polling `DriveInfo.GetDrives()`)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow rocks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715739/looking-for-c-code-for-detecting-removable-drive-usb-flash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a powershell module that uses a `System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher` and the WMI class `Win32_VolumeChangedEvent` to surface new events that you may register for within powershell covering device removal, addition etc. You should be able to figure out the relevant plumbing from this blog post of mine:

http://www.nivot.org/nivot2/post/2008/08/16/AutoMountunmountNewPSDrivesForRemovableDrivesAndNetworkSharesInPowerShellV2.aspx

You should be able to wire up an event for new drives in less than ten lines of C# using the methods I use in the above script.

Hope this helps.