# How to get the drive letter from a full name of the drive

Tags: c#, .net, windows, fileinfo, drive-letter

How could the drive letter (e.g. F:\) be obtained from a known full name (if it is present) of a drive (e.g. WORKMEMORYSTICK) using C# under Windows?

Even the other way around would be a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DriveInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) class exposes a method to get all available drives ([`GetDrives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx)), you could enyumerate these an match your given string. Something like the following ought to help get you there:

```
DirectoryInfo root;
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (var drive in drives)
{
    if (drive.VolumeLabel == label)
    {
        root = drive.RootDirectory;
        break;
    }
}
```

As mentioned by abatishchev, and not initially elaborated on due to the time requirements of my children, there is a potential problem in that you're only going to match the *first* drive which has that label, therefore you will need to account for this in your logic if your system requires it (though, determining which of two drives is *the* desired drive based on nothing but a non-unique string is no better than a guess, or as I mention below, asking the user (if this is input) which one they meant.)

Comment: That's not what `GetPathRoot()` does.  The OP is talking about finding the drive letter that corresponds to a volume label.

Comment: @cdhowie: Just realised... my mistake.

Comment: But what if more then one drive has the same label?

Answer (score 2):

You can cycle through all drives and check the Name and VolumeLabel [properties of DriveInfo object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.driveinfo_properties.aspx).

See this question for code examples (used to get the USB drive letter, but you can easily adapt it):

[How to find USB drive letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123927/how-to-find-usb-drive-letter)

Sorry I cannot provide you some code, but I'm on a Mac right now :)

Comment: But what if more then one drive has the same label?