# Editing android and iphone files trough wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

Hi to all I need some information about acessing android and iphone device trough wpf application I am using c sharp 2010 .

Comment: For android device check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072650/programmaticaly-access-files-on-android-device-from-pc

Comment: Thank you I need some startpoint and this is perfect .