# Portable USB device path obtained with shell32 - invalid characters in path

Tags: c#, windows, path, shell32, system.io.directory

I'm looking for a way to access files on a smartphone connected through USB cable using standard `System.IO` stuff like `Directory` and `StreamReader`.

I have obtained a pretty wicked-looking path to my USB device using this code:

```
public string GetDevicePath()
{
    dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));
    var folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select your Android device", 0);
    if (folder == null)
    {
        // user closed the dialog
        return null;
    }
    var fi = (folder as Folder3).Self;
    return fi.Path;
}
```

Which gets me a path like `::{20D0AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-0800AAAAAAAA}\\\?\usb#vid_12d1&pid_107e&mi_00#6&aaaaaaa&0&0000#{6ac2aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-f98faaaaaaaa}`. I can paste that into the Windows Explorer address bar and it redirects to something like `This PC\Samsung\Internal Storage`.

Obviously I can't do anything with that path e.g. `Directory.GetFiles()` because I get `InvalidPathException`.

How do access files from a path like that?

Comment: You should use the vendor driver for the USB device and not a generic Microsoft Driver.  I suspect the characters you are getting are due to the wrong usb driver that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Does this code work for you?

```
 public static string GetUsbPath(string usbLetterOrName) // "F:\" or "YourUsbName"
        {
            DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();            
            foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
            {
                if (d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                {
                    if(d.Name == usbLetterOrName || d.VolumeLabel == usbLetterOrName)
                    {
                        return d.RootDirectory.FullName;
                    }
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("Drive not found");
        }
```

And than accessing all files in usb

`var files = new DirectoryInfo(GetUsbPath("MyUsb")).GetFiles()`

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work for me. `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` gets only physical and network drives like `C:`, `D:`, `X:`. Usb devices are not in this list.

Comment: The code gets usb flash drives not devides ... my bad. You can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/60478286/10092614