# How to read data from a USB Device which is detected as CD ROM in c#

Tags: c#, usb

I want to read data from a USB Device which is detected as CD ROM How to do this with C#

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the drive letter?

Comment: @Shimmy I can find it dynamically but what after it ?

Comment: Please refer to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8460632/75500).

Answer (score 1):

You need the USB HID component - here's a tutorial with source code:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USB_HID.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In case you have the drive letter you can simply use [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx)/[`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx)/[`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) function.

Otherwise, look into getting USB device letter via: [How to find USB drive letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123927/how-to-find-usb-drive-letter).

Please be more specific on what 'data' refers to in your question to allow me providing you with additional info.

Comment: I have a question, what if I just wanted the file with a specific extension. E.g. on the CD-ROM drive, there's only one CSV file that I wanted to read. How do I get the path of that file from the CD-ROM drive?