# Get usb letter from DeviceNotifyEventArgs

Tags: c#, usb, cd

I can't find how to extract the inserted usb letter.

I have event that listen to usb that inserted, but I need the inserted letter, because I have mulpile usb ports.

```
void OnDeviceNotifyEvent(object sender, DeviceNotifyEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

Prints:

> [DeviceType:DeviceInterface] [EventType:DeviceArrival] FullName:USB#VID_2CE3&PID_6487#0000000000000000#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
>   Vid:0x2CE3
>   Pid:0x6487
>   SerialNumber:0000000000000000
>   ClassGuid:a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed

I'm using [LibUsbDotNet.DeviceNotify](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/html/e56de27a-7d1c-0b72-6396-8275caa85af5.htm) dll

For example: `E:\` inserted

Comment: What is usb letter? You mean letter of usb-drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find USB drive letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123927/how-to-find-usb-drive-letter)

Comment: @Sinatr That's not the same, because I want to get the letter from the event parameter

Comment: This event is generic event for usb devices, not usb drives. It provides you with no such info. But you can use some property (VID+PID? serial number? classguid?) to find that device using WMI and get its letter using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/124025/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr If you can then please post a code snippt as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `DeviceNotifyEventArgs` contains serial number you can use it to find device letter with help of WMI.

Here is adapted version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/124025/1997232):

```
// enumerate usb drives
foreach (var drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType='USB'").Get())
    // find driver with known serial number
    if ((string)drive.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value == serialNumber)
        // associate partitions with drive
        foreach (var partition in new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + drive["DeviceID"] + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition").Get())
            // associate logical disk with partition
            foreach (var disk in new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + partition["DeviceID"] + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition").Get())
                Console.WriteLine("Disk=" + disk["Name"]);
```

Make sure to wrap everything into `using`: all searchers and collection returned by `Get()` needs to be disposed.